# "ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length" при использовании dict

Tags: python

Не первый раз я натыкаюсь на эту ошибку, но не могу с ней справиться как в первый раз.
Имеется словарь:

```
{(43, 7): 1, (38, 7): 1}
```

который хранится строкой в файле, при попытке сделать эту строку словарем с помощью:

```
dict('{(43, 7): 1, (38, 7): 1}')
```

я получаю в ответ:

> ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is
>   required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import ast
s='{(43, 7): 1, (38, 7): 1}'
d=dict(ast.literal_eval(s))
```

Answer (score 2):

Чудес не бывает, питон не парсит строку в словарь. См. [поддерживаемый синтаксис](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#dict)

Comment: Действительно, спасибо за вразумительную ссылку на документацию, закодился :)

Answer (score 2):

Нельзя забывать о функции eval():

```
eval('{(43, 7): 1, (38, 7): 1}')
```